# ksh if with several conditions

Tags: ksh, test

I'd like to know what's the syntax for this kind of if in ksh :

```
if [[ $tmpEngine != "a" || $tmpEngine != "b" || $tmpEngine != "s" ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

Actually, my code doesn't work, what's the problem here ? 
The problem is not about the meaning of my if, but rather how to write it correctly from a syntax point of view.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever `$tmpEngine` value, this test is always true, I mean, `$tmpEngine` cannot be `a`, `b` and `s` at the same time so at least two of the comparisons are always true.

You probably want:

```
if [[ "$tmpEngine" != "a" && "$tmpEngine" != "b" && "$tmpEngine" != "s" ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: You right, small mistake from my side but anyway,
my code doesn't work because of a syntax problem.

Comment: Do you mean my answer doesn't address the problem described ?